# Android Hilt - How to share dependency between fragments?

Tags: android, dagger, dagger-hilt

How to share dependency between several specified fragments using Hilt/Dagger, but not all fragments?

I have single-activity-application. And have 3 fragments with creating one Entity.
For example create user:

```
... go to create user ...
1st fragment: enter phone -> put phone in interactor
2nd fragment: pick avatar -> put avatar in interactor
3rd fragment: enter name  -> put name in interactor + run
... success ...
```

And I want to start put data into interactor from 1st fragment, and finish put data on 3rd fragment and run interactor. And I expect that **interactor will be destroyed when all these 3 fragments is destroyed.**

If I mark interactor in Dagger as @Singleton or @ActivityScoped - it will have problems with reuse. Data in interactor will remain from previous starts.
If I make it unscoped or @FragmentScoped - fragments will have 3 different interactors.

Answer (score 1):

As one solution, you can put these 3 fragments in a Flow Fragment with its own navigation and DI graphs. The Flow DI container will share the Interactor between child fragments if you scope it (like @FlowScope). When user completes registration, the Flow Fragment will be popped up from app navigation graph, and the Interactor will be destroyed along with the Flow Fragment and its child fragments.